# add word "volume" to a custom bst

Tags: bibliographies, custom-bib

I'm editing the bibliography style "unsortnat" to satisfy a conference requirements.

The ask me to put at the end of the citation the volume and pages, after the year like :

> S. Adhikari, M. I. Friswell, D. J. Inman. Piezoelectric energy
>   harvesting from broadband random vibrations. Volume 18, pp. 115005.

Editing the bst file in the function

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
    { volume field.or.null
  number empty$
    'skip$
    { "{\ No.\ " number * "}" * *
      volume empty$
    { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ format.pages }
    { ",~pp.~" * pages n.dashify * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

I get this:

> S. Adhikari, M. I. Friswell, D. J. Inman. Piezoelectric energy
>   harvesting from broadband random vibrations. 18, pp. 115005.

the desired output but without the word "volume" which I don't know how to add it in the bst modification.

Any help will be appreciated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you mean you are modifying `unsrtnat.bst`.  In any case you need to rewrite the function a little to add this string because the first line

```
 volume field.or.null
```

immediately puts the volume number on to the stack when it is non null.  Here is one suggestion of how to rewrite:

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume empty$
  { number empty$
      { "" }
      { "\penalty0 (" number * ")" * *
        "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$
      }
    if$
  }
  { "Volume " volume *
    number empty$
      'skip$
      { "\penalty0 (" number * ")" * * }
    if$
  }
  if$
  pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ format.pages }
        { ":\penalty0 " * pages n.dashify * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

The logic is that we

- test whether `volume` is empty

  - if so test whether `number` is empty

    - if it is add a null string to the stack
    - otherwise provide the number information in brackets and warn that there is no volume number
  - if `volume` is not empty, print "Volume " and the volume number and then do a similar check on whether the `number` is non-empty or not, this time no warning is necessary.
  - thereafter proceed as before with the page information.

Calling the resulting file `myunsrtnat.bst` and using the standard `xampl.bst` contained in tex distributions, this gives

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citet{article-minimal,article-full,whole-collection}

\bibliographystyle{myunsrtnat}
\bibliography{xampl}

\end{document}
```

The first entry is an article without volume or number information, the second is a full detailed article, the third is another entry of a different type without these fields.

The `\pentaly`s are from a recent version of `unsrtnat.bst`.

Comment: That worked! Amazing reply. Thanks very much!